# chrome console.error stopped working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I've been relying on console.error for some time, but all of a sudden it just doesn't emit anything.

it still works in incognito mode.

i've disabled all the extensions one by one but that didn't fix it.

Comment: It doesn't by any chance [say "... messages are hidden by filters"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xrRS5.png)?

Comment: didn't see that.. even if type "console.error('foo')" in my dev console, i don't get anything back.. unless im in incognito mode. in which case it works

Comment: And am I right to assume that `console.log` and other levels work just fine?

Comment: console.log works, but console.warn also does not

Comment: If I enable filtering to just show logs, then that filter is maintained even when I restart Chrome. And indeed Incognito Mode keeps its own setting for that. Please post a screenshot like mine.

Comment: @Arjan that was it thanks!! somehow i missed the screenshot part of your post and looked through settings for this filter. somehow i never noticed those filters before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have no filtering enabled, which should then show *... messages are hidden by filters* on top of the console output:

[image: Filtering in console]

Once set, that filter is active even after restarting Chrome. And indeed Incognito Mode keeps its own setting for that.